# No route found for POST ... : Method Not Allowed (Allow: PUT)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3.x

Currently, I am updating the system running on the existing Symfony 2.3 (currently 3.0.9), and checking the operation.
When I tried to change the state of an item to the selected state, I got an error.
Do you have any advice for determining the case?

**Error Code**

```
No route found for "POST /admin/hq/article/3999/articleStatus": 
Method Not Allowed (Allow: PUT)
```

**Code**

ArticleController.php

```php
    /**
     * Article status change
     *
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Route("/article/{ids}/articleStatus")
     * @Secure(roles="ROLE_HQ_MANAGE")
     */
    public function updateArticleStatusAction(Request $request, $ids)
    {
        return parent::updateArticleStatusAction($request, $ids);
    }
```

**Version**

CentOS 6.7
PHP 5.6
Symfony3.0.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using a web browser to submit a form and the action goes to `/admin/hq/article/3999/articleStatus`  which only allows PUT operations (because of the `@Method("PUT")` annotation). Wheras submitting a form with a browser is a POST operation. Change that line to `@Method("POST")` and you should be fine.

Comment: the only possible reason for downvoting might be, that *some* api might be talking with this endpoint and using PUT requests, which this answer would break. I'd be a bit careful ...

Answer (score -1):

Go `vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php` and check line 80 in Symfony 6.2 and change this value from `false` to  `true`

```
protected static $httpMethodParameterOverride = true;
```

Comment: Editing code in the vendor directory directly is very bad practice! You should never do this unless you're planning on creating a patch. Instead `config/packages/framework.yml` should be updated by adding  `framework.http_method_override: true`